# ndk-build how to build opencore-amr

Tags: android, android-ndk, amr, opencore

I want to use opencore-amr native code in android jni.

but i don't know how to write Android.mk file.

can anyone tell me how?

I want to call the following function in opencore-amr lib:

> AMREncodeInit
>
> AMREncode
>
> AMREncodeExit

I download opencore-amr from http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/files/opencore-amr/

Comment: http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html

Comment: i just don't know how to build the open-amr~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a period of time, I figure it out myself:
See this project in github:

[opencore-amr-Android](https://github.com/mmedu/opencore-amr-Android)

I make a wrapper and build it with NDK

Answer (score 1):

See `make amr` and `make vo-amrwbenc` in https://github.com/juha-h/libbaresip-android Makefile.